# ESC/POS Command Answer

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2, thermal-printer, escpos

Good morning,

I am developing a kiosk application. In that application i need to send some commands to a printer with `ESC`/`POS` protocol.

I have some commands that give me information about printer (printer status, end of paper status). For sending command I use [this function](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showpost.php?p=19139&postcount=4), but I need also to read the printer reply. 
How can I do it? (The printer is connected in `USB` mode).

I'm developing on delphi xe2

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the last parameter to [Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should be a pointer to the data structure (nil in your linked example) to receive the output.

Comment: @TOndrej thanks, but i don't how is structured in delphi lpvOutData.. I tried like TPassThroughData of the example but without success..

Comment: Welcome. The structure probably depends on the printer and should be described in its documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure about it.. On the manual there isn't information. And I tried a lot of solution (array of byt, shortstring, string, integer..) but nothing is working

Comment: I'm not talking about a user manual, you need technical documentation aimed at developers.

Comment: @TOndrej i was talking about developer manual. The type that the printer returns are byte.

Answer (score 0):

The example is assuming that your string type is simple such as `shortstring`.  Try declaring `s` as `shortstring`.  It can not work with `widestring` or `unicode`.

Comment: procedure stampa(s: shortstring);
type
  TPassThroughData = record
    nLen: Integer;
    Data: array [0 .. 255] of Byte;
  end;

var
  PTBlock: TPassThroughData;
  PTReply: TPassThroughData;
begin
  Printer.BeginDoc;

  PTBlock.nLen := Length(s);
  StrPCopy(@PTBlock.Data, s);
  Escape(Printer.Handle, PASSTHROUGH, 0, @PTBlock, @PTReply);

  Printer.EndDoc;
end;

Something change, but nothing change...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the USB connection makes a new serial port?

If a new serial port displayed in device manager, I can help you to send the ESC command with a Delphi Comport component.

But if there is no serial port shown up, I have no idea about how to control the thermal printer.